# How to implement linux pipeline in windows using C\C++

Tags: c++, c, process, redirect, io-redirection

for example, in linux the following command

```
$ firstProgram | secondProgram
```

carries the output of firstProgram as an input to secondProgram

the basic code in C that makes it happen in linux is

```
#include <unistd.h>
.
.
.
int fd[2];
forkStatus = fork();
if (status == 0)
{
  close(1);
  dup(fd[1]);
  close(fd[1]);
  close(fd[0]);
  execv("firstProgram",...);
}
forkStatus = fork();
if (status == 0)
{
  close(0);
  dup(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
  close(fd[0]);
  execv("secondProgram",...);
}
close(fd[1]);
close(fd[0]);
```

i need to do something similar in windows. 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

See the Win32 `CreatePipe()` to create an anonymous pipe. [This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (titled "Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output") shows how to replicate your code in Win32.

Answer (score 0):

In the linux version you are basically redirecting the input and output. This can be done using the native Win32 API or if .NET is permissible System.* library. you can find more examples on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx